# Read feature table with FME / Python

Tags: python, esri-geodatabase, fme-form

I try to convert a feature table Geodatabase to MapInfo with FME / Python 
But each test, my application crash.
There is no geometry in my feature table in file geodatabase.
Why my application crashes with attribute table ?

```
    writerTab=FMEWriter("MITAB")
writerTab.open(RepMapInfo)

schemaTab=FMEFeature()
while reader.readSchema(schemaTab):
    #print writerTab.getSchemaFeatures()
    log.logFeature(schemaTab)
    writerTab.addSchema(schemaTab)

while reader.read(schemaTab):
    log.logFeature(schemaTab)
    writerTab.write(schemaTab)
```

The code is very simple.
Help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Workbench there is a parameter called "Ignore Failed Readers" that would do the job:

[image]

The syntax in the mapping file is:

```
[READER_NAME]_CONTINUE_ON_READER_FAILURE Yes
```

...I'm not sure how that would translate to Python - though I'm not sure why Python is required in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

use one 'fake' feature for the process then delete it after the conversion process.

Comment: A sample ? please.

Comment: you need to take geometry from your geodatabase (this can be stored as point,line polygon) then take the source to one geometry (ie point) in MapInfo - if your taking tables only you still need geometry (but can be deleted afterwards).

Comment: And is there a solution with Python ?